# Unit Testing that ModelBinder applied to MVC ActionResult parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I have a controller like:

`public ActionResult Index([ModelBinder(typeof(MyBinder))]int? MyId)`

I'd like to create a unit test `via Nunit+Moq+AutoFixture` to ensure that the MyId parameter is decorated with MyBinder, seems like a valid unit test given that if it is removed, the code will stop working as expected.  Obviously testing of the actual Custom Model Binder is done separately.

I expected it would be similar to testing that a property is decorated with specific attribute, such as below, but can't find how to access parameter in this way:

```
private readonly PropertyInfo _SomeProp = typeof(AddressViewModel).GetProperty("SomeProp");<br>
_SomeProp.Should().BeDecoratedWith&lt;DisplayAttribute&gt;();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fairly simple.

This is the MVC web app:

```
  public class MyBinder : IModelBinder
  {
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
      return default(int);
    }
  }

  public class DefaultController : Controller
  {
    public ActionResult Index([ModelBinder(typeof(MyBinder))] int? MyId)
    {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

And this is our NUnit test:

```
[Test]
public void Index_HasParamWithBinderAttribute()
{
  var targetType = typeof(DefaultController);
  var targetAction = targetType.GetMethod("Index", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public); // if there is an exception below, someone removed action from the controller

  var targetParams = targetAction.GetParameters().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "MyId"); // if there is an exception below, then someone renamed the action argument

  Assert.That(targetParams.ParameterType, Is.EqualTo(typeof(int?))); // if this fails, then someone changed the type of parameter
  Assert.That((targetParams.GetCustomAttributes(true).FirstOrDefault() as ModelBinderAttribute).BinderType, Is.EqualTo(typeof(MyBinder))); // if this fails, then either there is no more a modelbinder or the type is wrong
}
```